# Returning A Value In Node.js Express Using Cron

Tags: node.js, express, cron, return, cron-task

I've got Cron installed properly and everything, but I'm having trouble accessing a value returned from that function in the rest of my node app.

Basic Function:

```
module.exports.myFunction = function() {
    var job = new CronJob('00 0-59 * * * *', function() {
        var a = 5;
        var b = 2;

        return a + b;

        }, function () {
        },
        true
    );
}
```

I would think that returning the value here and then accessing it using a promise in one of my routes files would work, but it consistently returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`, which means `undefined` is being passed from the function.

Here's the code from my route file:

```
Tester.myFunction()
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log("Done!");
            console.log(data);

            req.flash('success', "You have successfully started the software!");

            res.render('dashboard');

        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
```

Since this isn't working, how can I properly return a value from a function when using Cron? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to return a Promise.

Comment: @Li357 I know, I just don't know the correct way to return that promise inside the Cron function. I've tried different positioning of the `return` statement, but none of them are working.

Comment: What do you want `data` to be?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you are trying to do. Do you want the behavior where the promise resolves when the cron job is scheduled — that's no problem. Or do you want the `then()` behavior when the cron jobs runs. That's more problematic. You aren't going to be able to return a value from this function, because you aren't calling the function. The cron module is calling the function. And it doesn't make sense to return a promise because it may be be called more that once, but promises only fire once.

Comment: @Li357 I would expect `data` to be 7, the returned value of `a + b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `Promise` from `myFunction` which resolves with the data you're currently returning, like so:

```
module.exports.myFunction = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var job = new CronJob('00 0-59 * * * *', function() {
                var a = 5;
                var b = 2;

                resolve(a + b);

            }, function() {},
            true
        );
    })
}
```

However, since a cron can run multiple times, but promise only resolves once, you can also use `EventEmitter`.

Change your `myFunction` as follows:

```
module.exports.myFunction = function() {
    const myFnEventEmitter = new(require('events').EventEmitter)();
    var job = new CronJob('00 0-59 * * * *', function() {
            var a = 5;
            var b = 2;

            myFnEventEmitter.emit('started', a + b)

        }, function() {},
        true
    );
    return myFnEventEmitter;
}
```

And where you're using it, do:

```
const myFnEventEmitter = Tester.myFunction();
myFnEventEmitter.on('started', data => {
    console.log("Done!");
    console.log(data);
    req.flash('success', "You have successfully started the software!");
    res.render('dashboard');
})
```

Comment: This worked - thank you! I was just unsure on how to properly return the promise. Appreciate the help

Comment: Quick question though, what if I wanted to run the function multiple times? That's why I am using Cron. Since a promise can fire once, wouldn't this create a problem?

Comment: Is EventEmitter a node module that will need installed?